# SSR app but React Router Navigation on the client side doesn't fetch data and breaks the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, server-side-rendering

I've created a SSR React app that loads data on the server and sends it to the client as html. The problem kicks in after the initial server request has been served and i try to switch to a different navigation link. The url changes to the correct path but the page itself breaks with a TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' or 'map' of undefined. I believe the fetching somehow is not working on the client side, because if i turn off JavaScript from the browser everything works just fine.

The App has four routes, Home, Movies (needs to fetch data), TvShows (needs to fetch data) and PageNotFound. Again, the problem occurs when for example I open the Home page and try to switch to Movies. However, if i open Movies or TvShows first everything loads correctly because of the initial request being served by the server. Here is my file structure: [image]

And here's the content of some of my files:

index.js (Server.js)

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
import express from "express";
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import Routes from "./client/Routes";
import { matchRoutes } from "react-router-config";
import renderer from "./helpers/renderer.js";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducers from "./reducers";
const compression = require("compression");

const app = express();

app.use(compression());

app.use(express.static("public")); //treats the public(client side) directory as public, available to the outside world

// This is fired every time the server side receives a request

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  // Create a new Redux store instance
  const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk));

  const promises = matchRoutes(Routes, req.path)
    .map(({ route }) => {
      return route.loadData ? route.loadData(store) : null;
    })
    .map((promise) => {
      if (promise) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          promise.then(resolve).catch(resolve);
        });
      }
    });

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    // Send the rendered page back to the client
    // Grab the initial state from our Redux store
    const context = {};
    //const finalState = store.getState();
    const content = renderer(req, store, context);

    if (context.notFound) {
      res.status(404);
    }

    res.send(content);
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT);
```

client.js

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { renderRoutes } from "react-router-config";
import Routes from "./Routes";
import reducers from "../reducers";

// Grab the state from a global variable injected into the server-generated HTML
const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;


// Create Redux store with initial state
const store = createStore(reducers, preloadedState, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

renderer.js

```
import React from "react";
import serialize from "serialize-javascript";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Routes from "../client/Routes";
import { renderRoutes } from "react-router-config";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

// Render the component to a string
export default (req, store, context) => {
  const html = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={context}>
        <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  );

  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

  return `
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
        <head>
        ${helmet.title.toString()}
        ${helmet.meta.toString()}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="root">${html}</div>
          <script>
            // WARNING: See the following for security issues around embedding JSON in HTML:
            // https://redux.js.org/recipes/server-rendering/#security-considerations
            window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${serialize(store.getState())}
          </script>
          <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
        </body>
      </html>
      `;
};
```

Routes.js

```
 import App from "./App";
    import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
    import MovieListPage from "./pages/MovieListPage";
    import TvShowsPage from "./pages/TvShowsPage";
    import NotFoundPage from "./pages/NotFoundPage";
    
    //using spread operator for the components
    //and loadData function(if available)
    //because they are imported in object form now
    export default [
      {
        ...App, //no path added to App, meaning it will always be displayed on screen
        routes: [
          {
            ...HomePage,
            path: "/",
            exact: true,
          },
          {
            ...MovieListPage,
            path: "/movies",
            exact: true,
          },
          {
            ...TvShowsPage,
            path: "/tvshows",
            exact: true,
          },
          {
            ...NotFoundPage, //will be shown if react router can't match any of the defined routes
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

MovieListPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchMovies } from "../../actions";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

class MovieListPage extends Component {
  // Have state ready for both Movies and TvShows link clicks/direct requests
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.movies) return;
    this.props.fetchMovies();
  }

  renderData() {
    return this.props.movies.results.map((movie) => {
      return (
        <div
          key={movie.id}
          className="card text-center m-3"
          style={{ width: "15rem" }}
        >
          <img
            className="card-img-top"
            alt="..."
            src={this.dynamicUrl(movie)}
          />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{movie.title}</h5>
            <p className="card-text font-weight-light">{movie.release_date}</p>
            <a href={this.dynamicLink(movie)} className="btn btn-secondary">
              TMDB
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  dynamicUrl(movie) {
    let url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/" + movie.poster_path;
    return url;
  }

  dynamicLink(movie) {
    let link = "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/" + movie.id;
    return link;
  }

  head() {
    return (
      <Helmet>
        <title>{`${this.props.movies.results.length} Movies Loaded`}</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Movies" />
      </Helmet>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.head()}
        <div className="row">{this.renderData()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { movies: state.movies };
}

function loadData(store) {
  return store.dispatch(fetchMovies());
}

//exporting the component and the loadData function (if present)
//in the form of an object(key:value pair)
// to avoid overlap of different loadData function imports in Routes

export default {
  loadData,
  component: connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchMovies })(MovieListPage),
};
```

I can't seem to figure out what is it that i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in renderer.js. I didn't provide the correct path for my client-side bundle.js in the html served by the server. Instead of  `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>` it had to be  `<script src="/public/bundle.js"></script>.`